# How to write a trigger that shows an error after creating five contact record on a account object

Tags: apex, trigger

How to write a trigger that shows an error after creating five contact records related to an account object?

Comment: Hi @Jai, welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to visit the [help] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

If you are not familiar with Apex, I suggest you take a look to the documentation.

There is a method called `addError` which marks the record as faulty. With this, Salesforce throws an error to the user and does not save the record.

I'm assuming you want to limit the number of contacts that can be related to an account record.

```
trigger Contact on Contact (before insert) {
    // it is important to separe your trigger logic into contexts
    // so you can use the same trigger for other situations on
    // the same object
    if (Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isInsert) {
        // get account ids to query the amount
        Set<Id> account_ids = new Set<Id>();
        for (Contact record : Trigger.new) {
            account_ids.add(record.AccountId);
        }
        // query the contact count grouping by account
        List<AggregateResult> ars = [SELECT
            COUNT(Id),
            AccountId
            FROM Contact
            WHERE AccountId IN :account_ids
            GROUP BY AccountId
        ];
        Map<Id, Integer> accounts_contact_count = new Map<Id, Integer>();
        // iterate the results and separate it to a map:
        // account (id) => contact count (int)
        for (AggregateResult ar : ars) {
            accounts_contact_count.put(
                Id.valueOf(ar.get('AccountId')),
                Integer.valueOf(ar.get('expr0'))
            );
        }
        // iterate again your contact records, but this time you can check
        // if the account already has 5 contacts. If it does, add an error
        // to the record, so it won't be saved and the user will receive
        // the error message you specify
        for (Contact record : Trigger.new) {
            if (accounts_contact_count.get(record.AccountId) == 5) {
                record.addError('Accounts must have a maximum of 5 contacts.');
            }
        }
    }
}
```